# How i can use \IfFileExist{FileName}{}{} with spaces in FileName

Tags: graphics

Have anyone an idea how i can use `\IfFileExist{}{}{}` for file names with spaces?

f.e. didn't work

```
\newcommand{\runI}{D:/Test/run1 - T2}
\newcommand\IG[2][]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{\fbox{File #2 doesn't exist}}}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\IG[trim = 40mm 10mm 40mm 2mm,clip = true, width=0.4\textwidth]{\runI/LatexTestFig2.png}
\caption{run 1}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
```

f.e. work

```
\newcommand{\runII}{D:/Test/run1-T2-Kopie}
\newcommand\IG[2][]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{\fbox{File #2 doesn't exist}}}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\IG[trim = 40mm 10mm 40mm 2mm,clip = true, width=0.4\textwidth]{\runII/LatexTestFig2.png}
\caption{run 1}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
```

what can I do? THX

Comment: Completely untested and just an idea: have you checked out the `grffile` package? http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/grffile.pdf

Comment: As `graphics` will give a warning here anyway, is there a reason you are adding a test by hand?

Comment: `grffile` would have been my first guess as well, but remember: spaces in filenames are evil http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129

Comment: The kpathsea file library used by most TeX distributions allows `"` to be used to  quote a filename containing bad characters like spaces so  `"\runI/LaTeXFile.png"` should work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made a test and needed the analog of `"\runI/LaTeXFile".png`. But this is on TL2010, if it matters.

Comment: @jfbu ah yes the includegraphics macro needs to see the extension but that's me not kpathsea:-) Thanks for the correction. the underlying file access doesn't much care where the " are as long as they surround the spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 2019-10-01 releases, LaTeX automatically uses the `"` quoting feature in the background so all of these should work without the user needing any explicit quotes

```
\IfFileExists{space name.foo}{yes}{no}

\input{my tex file}

\includegraphics{my picture}

\includegraphics{my picture.png}
```

Despite adding this feature it is still recommended that users don't put spaces in filenames.

---

**Original answer**

The kpathsea file library used by most TeX distributions allows `"` to be used to quote a filename containing bad characters like spaces so

```
 "\runI/LaTeXFile.png"
```

should work for `\IfFileExists` however as pointed out by jfbu the `\includegraphics` macro would see that as an unknown extension `.png"` so for `\includegraphics` you would want

```
 "\runI/LaTeXFile".png
```

To quote the spaces while leaving the `.png` extension visible.