# Problem reading .bib file in RevTex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

I'm trying to write a paper using RevTex 4.1 and natbib 8.31b, and the .bib file is not being recognized.  My paper is:

```
\documentclass[aip,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % need for subequations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
... {Text of document}
% Create the reference section using BibTeX:
%\bibpliographystyle{aipauth4-1}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

and my .bib file (excerpt) is:

```
@article{AharonovBohn1959//
,title = "Significance of Electromagnetic Potentials in Quantum Theory"//
,author = "Y. Aharonov and D. Bohm"
,journal = "The Physical Review"
,pages = "485-491"
,year = 1959
}

@article{vanOudenaardenDevoretetal1998
,title = "Matneto-electric Aharonov-Bohm effect in metal rings"
,author = "A. van Oudenaarden, M. H. Devoret, Y. V. Nazarov & J. E. Mooij"
,journal = "Nature"
,pages = "768-770"
,year = 1998
}
... etc.
```

When I run pdfLaTex in TeXworks the paper compiles fine with no errors or warnings.  When I then run BibTeX I again get no errors or warnings, but when I run pdfLaTeX again I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./PhysicsFromFrequencyV1-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...

Package natbib Warning: Citation `AharonovBohn1959' on page 4 undefined on input line 305.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `vanOudenaardenDevoretetal1998' on page 4 undefined on input line 305.
```

Running pdfLaTeX multiple times does not resolve this error.  It seems like natbib is not seeing the References.bib file, but I don't know what else to do to connect the two together.

Does anyone have any advice about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you only run pdfLaTeX or also BibTex? For instance Texmaker does not run it by default, so you'll probably need to run it manually (or probably have a look at [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/), which will run everything neccessary as often as neccesary).

Comment: Tom:  Thanks for responding.  I was running bibtex after pdfLaTeX, and then pdfLaTeX again (several times).  Just a few minutes ago I managed to fix the problem.  The main problem was the "&" in the second bibliography entry.  Another problem was my tex filename had a space, bibtex apparently doesn't like that at all.  When I fixed these two problems everything compiled properly.  It would be nice if the error/warning messages were a little more specific.

Comment: Yeah, error messages are not really a strong suit. As your problem was resolved by escaping the `&` and removing spaces from the file name, issues whih have already been discussed in several questions, I'm voting to close this as "duplicate" of e.g. **[this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%c3%a4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography)** or **[this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180554/how-i-can-use-iffileexistfilename-with-spaces-in-filename)**