# TikZ: Image is up-to-date. error: (file) (pdf backend): internal error: unknown image type

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-external

What causes the following error?

> ===== Image 'rect.tikz' is up-to-date. ======
> ./rect.tikz:3: error:  (file rect.tikz) (pdf backend): internal error: unknown image type
> ./rect.tikz:3:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

```
\documentclass[
addpoints,
]{exam}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{rect.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em,blue]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Diaa} (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfile,lipsum,graphbox,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount,multicol,multirow,calc,tikz,calc,mathtools,tikzscale,lua-ul,enumitem,xfrac,siunitx,comment,matlab-prettifier,atveryend,pdfpages,afterpage,lastpage,longtable,pgfmath,xfp,ifthen}

% https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1562#a1814
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@external@watch@store@aux#1#2{%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\xdef\noexpand\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\string\endcsname{#2}}}%
\def\tikz@external@watch@get@from@aux#1#2{%
    \ifcsname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\endcsname
    \edef#2{\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\endcsname}%
    \else
    \edef#2{0}%
    \fi}
\tikzset{external/watch/.cd,store/.code 2 args={%
        \tikz@external@watch@store@aux{#1}{#2}},
    get/.code 2 args={\tikz@external@watch@get@from@aux{#1}{#2}},
    font size/.code={\tikzset{external/watch/get={font size}{\pgfutil@tempa},
            external/watch/store={font size}{\f@size}}%
        \unless\ifnum\pgfutil@tempa=\f@size
        \tikzset{/tikz/external/force remake}%
        \fi
}}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{external}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482560/2288
% https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=1605&id=85129#c85129
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[1]{%
    \tikzset{external/export=true}%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
    \input{#1}%
    \tikzset{external/export=false}%
}

\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}% xparse,breakable
\tcbset{shield externalize}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
% https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=1605&id=85129#c85129
\tikzset{external/.cd, 
    watch/font size, 
    export = false}

\inputtikz{rect.tikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Name the PDF to be produced by `rect.tikz`, call it, say, `myrect` and add a second parameter to your macro.  `rect.tikz` is the name of the text file containing the code for the tikz picture. Name the PDF with `\tikzsetnextfilename{#2}` (if you make the PDF name the second parameter. Then your macro call becomes `\inputtikz{rect.tikz}{myrect}`.

Comment: @Cicada You are right. Additionally, I found that spaces in names make error. Do you have any idea how to make the following work with spaces: `\NewDocumentCommand{\inputtikz}{ m m }{%
\tikzset{external/export=true}%
\tikzsetnextfilename{#2}%
\input{#1}%
\tikzset{external/export=false}%
}` with `\inputtikz{{"the rect"}.tikz}{{"my rect"}}`?

Comment: `\inputtikz{"b rect.tikz"}{myrect}` works for me (Windows). Ask a separate question to get a proper answer for your setup. No-one will look under `errors` `tikz-external` for a space-in-filename question buried in the comments.

Comment: Possibly related to the secondary question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180554/how-i-can-use-iffileexistfilename-with-spaces-in-filename

Comment: @Cicada Ulrike spoke the truth here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56527285#56527285

Comment: For reference, Ulrike's comment on the chat link is: "@Diaa file names with spaces works ok in simple conditions like inputting a graphic or a file. But you should use them in complicate setups e.g. where external tools are called, only if you, and I mean you, are willing to spent a lot time to get the quoting right. This kind of stuff breaks if there are not enough and too much quotes, and if the chain is longer every step must be adjusted to the previous. "